# An Entire function with a condition.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an entire function. Suppose, for each $a\in \mathbb{R}$, there exists at least one coefficient $c_{n}$ in $f(z)=\sum c_{n}(z-a)^{n},$ which is zero. Then prove that there exist $k\geq 0$ such that $f^{(n)}(0)= 0$ for all $n\geq k.$
Where $f^{(n)}(0)$ means its n th derivative at zero.

Comment: The given condition just says that at each reals either function value is zero or its derivative is zero at that point. Then how to prove that after some stage function derivative is zero at zero?

Comment: Please do not simply dump your homework problems here. Instead, please indicate what you're stuck on, what you've tried so far, and the context of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: for $n=0,1,2,\cdots,$  let $E_n= \{a \in \mathbb {R}: f^{(n)}(a) = 0\}.$ Argue that one of the $E_n$'s is uncountable and proceed. (There's a proof using Baire here, but we don't need to use that.)

Comment: @YOGESH please spend more than just a few minutes thinking about this.

Comment: yes uncountable because of set of reals is uncountable..

Comment: ok its uncountable...now i make two case firstly is bounded set then the problem is solved....second one its unbouded uncountable then how to proceeds??

Comment: ok ok i got the point..... now by using identity theorem.....function will be a polynomial...... am i correct ...please tell am i correct.??